# Exclude topic from namespace

Tags: navigation, mapping, namespace, amcl, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a Turtlebot running the navigation stack and a workstation that runs the corresponding map-server.

The amcl node is launched in a namespace so that all published and subscribed topics get prefixed with that namespace. So amcl is subscribing to /namespace/map instead of just /map.

Now I want to exclude the map topic from the namespace so that amcl subscribes to /map again but all other topics should still be prefixed.
I tried to remap it from "map" to "/map" but that didnt't change anything.

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201433/exclude-topic-from-namespace/) by [DKS](https://answers.ros.org/users/21308/dks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default amcl will get the map not via the topic, but via a service call (http://wiki.ros.org/amcl), so you need to remap that instead.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0